# Api from Asp core controller not receive all the value that FormData.append(key,value) appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, form-data

I want to upload files(image, setup file) and some other text string together.
This is my ajax code:

```
function uploadFiles(inputId) {

var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
var files = input.files;
formData = new FormData();

for (var i = 0; i !== files.length; i++) {
    var temp1 = files[i];
}

formData.append('temp', 1);
formData.append('temp', "ksjhdfksdjf");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Admin/FileUploadView/SaveEntity",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

    beforeSend: function () {
        tedu.startLoading();
    },
    success: function () {

    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
}
```

This is my controller:

[image]

When I log all the files that formData object contain, everything is ok:

[image]

But I only receive 2 image's objects in the controller:

[image]

Now I want that I can receive all the files that I appended. Do you have any ideas, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not receive your `temp` in your controller.

js:

```
function uploadFiles(inputId) {
    var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
    var files = input.files;
    var formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
        formData.append("files", files[i]);
    }
    formData.append('temp', 1);
    formData.append('temp', "ksjhdfksdjf");
   //ajax
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveEntity(IList<IFormFile> files,List<string> temp)
```